# How can I create a program that count votes that are being put by the user

Tags: python

I need to make 3 political parties like in an election. The program should ask "for which will you vote?" (showing the 3 political options), after 10 the user randomly inserts 10 votes, the program should count the votes and print the results.

I'm new to programming, I really don't know what I'm doing

```
print("today is election day! for who will u vote?")
polls=print("PLD","PRM","PRD")
```

Comment: It would be better to share some code or the command you've used.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] (we can see that you haven't) and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This question is off-topic because it's too broad. We're not here to write code for you. You might also want to read this [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: I've not done any actual coding, just the beginning of printing the 3 political parties, the rest, I don't know how to do it. I'll try to compile something and post it, to see if you gus can tell where im being wrong

Comment: `print()` always return `None` so using `polls = print(...)` is useless.

Comment: you may need `input()` to ask for votes, `for`-loop to ask 10 users, lists to keep votes, `your_list.count("PLD")` to count votes for `PLD`

Answer (score 0):

1) In your question, you stated "after 10...", after 10 what?

Im assuming that if was just a typo.

Here's the code for the program. All you need to do is figure out how to stop asking once it the vote count is greater than or equal to 10. You learn and retain information best when you struggle, trust me.

If you have any questions about the syntax used, feel free to drop a comment.

```
parties = ['PLD', 'PRM', 'PRD']
max_votes = 10
num_votes = 0
print('~'*40)
print(f'\n~ Today is election day!\n~ You have {vote_count} votes to use\n~ Use them wisely!\n')
print('~'*40)
print(f' Polical Parties: {parties[:]}')
print('~'*40,'\n')


"""
 As declared above, "num_votes" is the variable that is being used to keep
 track of how many votes the user has used so far.
 The += operator adds the value of the variable on the right to the existing
 value of the variable on the left. It would be the same as saying:
  >>> num_votes = num_votes + PLD_votes

So, its just saving the number of votes used to the varible "num_votes".
"""
PLD_votes = int(input(f'\nHow many votes for "{parties[0]}": '))
num_votes += PLD_votes 
num_votes = input(f'\nHow many votes for "{parties[1]}": ')
num_votes += PRM_votes
PRD_votes = input(f'\nHow many votes for "{parties[2]}": ')
vote_count += PRD_votes

print('Here are the results...\n')
print(f'{parties[0]}: {PLD_votes}\n{parties[1]}: {PRM_votes}\n{parties[2]}: {PLD_votes}')

"""
The use of "f" and "{}" within strings is a way of formating the string to return letters with variables in them.

Example: print(f'Number of votes: {num_votes}') *mind the 'f'*

Here, typing 'f' before the quotations tells the program that you are going to be using "{}" within the string. What goes inside of the curlies "{}" are variables that you want to print along with the string. I prefer this 

There are many different ways of accomplishing this:

Concatenation:
   >>> print('Number of votes' + num_votes)

Using %d ('d' for numbers; for variable which contain strings you would use '%s'):
   >>> print('Number of votes %d')

There are more ways of doing it, I just prefer using {} because to me it seems more straightforward to read.

"""
```

Comment: Thank you Burned Money, the lines I don't understand its functions are 10,12,14. On the other hand ( if you want to explain) what is the purpose of the " { " and " f' ". Thank you again for helping me out.

Comment: No problem. I just changed the lines which you are asking about, I just messed up (since I coded this around 12am...tired). I'll edit my response to include explanations for which you are asking for.

Comment: If you think that I have answered your question, please mark it as so.